# Request format to tweet an image

Tags: php, twitter

I can't find the right format to post an update in Twitter, It's seems to obvious that no one explain it.

I'm Using PHP and a http_socket_oauth lib from http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/04/12/cakephp-oauth-extension-to-httpsocket/

The really hard part for me is the 'media[]' parameter, I don't know exactly where to put it, and how it should be written. I've try to many things but always get the same error:

> {"errors":[{"code":195,"message":"Missing or invalid url parameter."}]}

This is the request what I think must be ok, but it isn't:

```
$request = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
        ),
        'uri' => array(
          'host' => 'api.twitter.com',
          'path' => '1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
          'scheme' => 'https',
        ),
        'auth' => array(
          'method' => 'OAuth',
          'oauth_token' => $this->Session->read('Twitter.oauth_token'), // From session
          'oauth_token_secret' => $this->Session->read('Twitter.oauth_token_secret'), // From session
          'oauth_consumer_key' => Configure::read('Twitter.consumer_key'), // APP key
          'oauth_consumer_secret' => Configure::read('Twitter.consumer_secret'), // APP secret
        ),
        'body' => array(
          'status' => 'This is a Test ',
          'media[]' => '@{http://www.mydomail.com/img/Drop100.gif},
        ),
      );
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot post an image from a URL (http://....).  What happens when you try posting a *local* image?

Comment: I've tried that to: `$handle    = fopen(WWW_ROOT.DS.'img'.DS.'Dropial-logo-128.png','rb');
        $image     = fread($handle,filesize(WWW_ROOT.DS.'img'.DS.'Dropial-logo-128.png'));
        fclose($handle);` and then using this `'media[]' => '@{'.$image.'};type={image/png};filename={Dropial-logo-128.png}'` But get the same error.

Comment: Also try using a hard coded path: `'media[]' => '{'.WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'Dropial-logo-128.png'.'};type={image/png};filename={Dropial-logo-128.png}'` and same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

The problem is that the http_socket_oauth lib from http://www.neilcrookes.com/2010/04/12/cakephp-oauth-extension-to-httpsocket/ doesn't prepare data for multipart form. So I add the handle for Multipart just before sending the request.

The Request from my controller is built this way:

```
        $request = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            ),
            'uri' => array(
              'host' => 'api.twitter.com',
              'path' => '1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
              'scheme' => 'https',
            ),
            'auth' => array(
              'method' => 'OAuth',
              'oauth_token' => $this->Session->read('Twitter.oauth_token'), // From Session
              'oauth_token_secret' => $this->Session->read('Twitter.oauth_token_secret'), // From Session
              'oauth_consumer_key' => Configure::read('Twitter.consumer_key'),
              'oauth_consumer_secret' => Configure::read('Twitter.consumer_secret'),
            ),
            'data' => array(
                'media[]' => './img'.DS.'Dropial-logo-128.png',
            ),
            'body' => array(
              'status' => 'This is a test!',
            ),
          );
```

The code I added to the http_socket_oauth lib is:

```
if(isset($request['header']['Content-Type']) && $request['header']['Content-Type']=='multipart/form-data'){
App::uses('String', 'Utility');
    $boundary = String::uuid();

    $body = "--{$boundary}\r\n";

    foreach ($request['body'] as $key => $value) {
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$key}\"\r\n";
        $body .= "\r\n";
        $body .= "{$value}\r\n";
        $body .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";
    }

    foreach ($request['data'] as $key => $path) {
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$key}\"; filename=\"{$path}\"\r\n";
        $body .= "\r\n";
        $body .= file_get_contents($path) . "\r\n";
        $body .= "--{$boundary}--\r\n";
    }
    $request['body'] = $body;
    $request['header']['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data; boundary={$boundary}";
}
```

As you can see I had to rewrite the body and header param.

This is just before

```
return parent::request($request);
```

That's it. Thank you anyway Terence!